# Fatal Error on PHP Fine Diff

Tags: php, diff, require-once

I am trying to include 'finediff.php' but i am getting an error message.

> "Fatal error: Class 'FineDiff' not found in".

Any idea what am i missing here? Below are the codes

> require_once ( get_template_directory_uri(). '/inc/finediff.php');
>
> > $opcodes = FineDiff::getDiffOpcodes($string_old, $string_new /* , default granularity is set to character */);

Comment: Do you use namespaces? try \FineDiff::

Comment: Can we get a head -20 of inc/finediff.php?

Comment: This cant be the case. Here is how i include wordpress upload. require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );and is working fine

Comment: SEE: Warning: require_once(http://test.com/wp-content/themes/test\inc\finediff.php): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /home4/test/public_html/wp-content/themes/test/page-translate-user.php on line 3

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work!

> `require_once _DIR__ . '/inc/finediff.php';`

Comment: the underscore is missing in this post. __DIR